# How to run more than one function synchronously in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I've `componentDidUpdate()` which has two functions in it as follows:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
      if (prevProps !== this.props){
        this.getListHistory()
        this.forceUpdate()
      }
    }
```

In `this.getListHistory()` function there is a asynchronous firestore function so when I tried to execute `this.forceUpate()` function it doesn't wait for the `getListHistory()`.

Now I want my `this.forceUpdate()` function to wait for the `getListHistory()`  completion but I don't want to disturb the code inside the `getListHistory()`.How can I do that?

Comment: What is `getListHistory` doing? Is it setting some state? How is it persisting the state across refreshes? Using setState will cause a component to re-render so you should be doing this instead of `forceUpdate`. Using `forceUpdate()` is not recommended for most situations.

Comment: `prevProps !== this.props` this is always `true`; its only checking the object refrence; hence `shallow comparison`

Answer (score 0):

you should return a promise as the return value of `this.getListHistory()` and call `this.forceUpdate()` in it's `.then()`; check out the examples below:

```js
function getListHistory(){
 // your codes
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  // some code maybe
  //you can also have a return value passed to resolve like this; resolve("someReturnValue")
  resolve()
 })
```

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
 if (/* some condition*/){
  this.getListHistory().then( value => this.forceUpdate())
 }
}
```